# Proving the dimension formula for subsets using the dimension formula for linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra

Let K be a field,  $U_1, U_2 \subset V$ subspaces of a vector space $V$ over $K$.

Prove that $$\dim_K(U_1)+\dim_K(U_2)=\dim_K(U_1+U_2)+\dim_K(U_1 \cap U_2)$$

using

$$\dim_K(\ker(f))+\dim_K(\operatorname{im}(f))=\dim_K(H)$$

for a linear map $f: H \rightarrow W$ for vector spaces $H, W$ over $K$.

I would love some hints, I know how to prove this using the basis of the subspaces, but this way is unknown to me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It should be $H$ instead of $W$ on the second equation, right?

Comment: Correct! Thank you

Comment: I suppose you mean subspaces instead of subsets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the linear map $(u_{1}, u_{2}) \mapsto u_{1} + u_{2}$ from $U_{1} \times U_{2}$ to $U_{1}+U_{2}$.

Comment: Is it allowed to use a specific linear map? Doesn't it need to be more general to prove it?

Comment: Ok, I understand now. 
$$dim_K(ker(f))=dim_K(U_1 \cap U_2)$$
$$dim_K(im(f))=dim_K(U_1 + U_2)$$
$$dim_K(U_1 \times U_2)=dim_K(U_1)+dim_K(U_2)$$
Correct?

Comment: Yes, you only need a few arguments to prove the 3 equalities.

Comment: I reversed your edit. It is really $U_1 \times U_2$, that is to say the set of all pairs $(u_1, u_2)$ when $u_1\in U_1$ and $u_2\in U_2$ and not $U_1 \oplus U_2$. The latter is only a notation for $U_1+U_2$ in the special case where $U_1\cap U_2=\{0\}$

Comment: I have been taught that $V \oplus W=(V\times W, +, \cdot )$, excuse me if I was wrong.

Comment: Your definition is the definition of the [external direct sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/topics/DirectSumsandProducts.html). I think it leads to confusion. In this context, it is only a way to stress that $V\times W$ is a vector space. On the other hand the (internal) direct sum of two subspaces as a way to mean $U_1 + U_2$ and to stress that their intersection is $\{0\}$ is very useful.